# How do I parse this JSON data in C# and would it be more benefical to simply switch over to javascript?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, import.io

I'm looking to parse this JSON and I've had nothing but problems. The link to the JSON is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Z7n.png). I'm trying to access the "href" field. While writing this up, I realized that that the data field is actually an array so that is part of my problem.

```
class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\...\file.json");
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        var x = myDeserializedClass.result.extractorData.data;
        Console.Write(x.ToString());
    }

    public class Newcolumn
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string xpath { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string filepath { get; set; }
        public string fileMimeType { get; set; }
        public int fileTotalBytes { get; set; }
        public string fileLastModifiedTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public List<Newcolumn> Newcolumn { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public List<Group> group { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExtractorData
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    }

    public class PageData
    {
        public int statusCode { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Inputs
    {
        public string _url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public ExtractorData extractorData { get; set; }
        public PageData pageData { get; set; }
        public Inputs inputs { get; set; }
        public string taskId { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public int sequenceNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

}

This ends up returning: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp3.Datum]
```

I notice that the field name data actually turns into an array though I'm not sure how to structure that. data.[0].new Column.[0].group.etc... does not work obviously. The space in the "new Column" field is also problematic. Additionally, when I debug and look at the JSON viewer, the "new column field is null. I also tried this code:

```
public static void Main()
{

    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\...\file.json");
    dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    var a = stuff.result.extractorData.data; 
    string b = a.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(b);         
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This actually does return the data field object however, if I do stuff.result.extractorData.data.group; I get this:

```
 Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message='Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'group'
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I assume that this is probably because of the array contained within the data field, regardless the "new Column' field is also an issue with this method due to the space.

Comment: Have you tried `Newtonsoft.Json`? It's quite popular among .NET developers.

Comment: @Kettle3D JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is Method of Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Okay. I've had a few too many problems with JSON, I prefer to use XML.

Answer (score 0):

in your above code

```
 public class ExtractorData
 {
     public string url { get; set; }
     public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
 }
```

where data is List and you are trying to access as string

```
 Console.Write(x.ToString());
```

in data variable Datum is List ( where your variable have multiple Data) and in every element there is a List. (Nestest List Concept Applied in This JSON)

Try to Add Break Point on below Line and check the line by line Excution of Code.

```
var a = stuff.result.extractorData.data;
```

After Looking Your JSON File Image Try This Code

```
Console.Write(a.FirstOrDefault()?.group.FirstOrDefault()?.Newcolumn.FirstOrDefault()?.href);
```